# always get same coordinates from CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, core-location

i'd like to use CLLocationManager to get current position on each tap on a button, but always get the same coordinates :(

```
- (void)GetCoord
{
    self.currentLocation = nil;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
        initWithTitle:@"Megerősítés" 
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f ::: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude] 
        delegate:self 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Nem" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil
    ];

    [alert show];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Are you running this through the simulator? Maybe you are simulating that location. Check the little current location icon in Xcode above the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  -(void) updateLocation
    {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        userLocation.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        userLocation.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        //Send any notification to your controller about the update location.
    }
```